# How to set group icon size of Expandable list in android?

Tags: android, icons, expandablelistview

I want to set give a custom group icon to expandable list view but the image that i have give will stretch by Android

The screenshot of my list is follows

[image]

As you can see the group icon (+) is stretched

How can i arrange into default size

I have tried with the following image size

36x36

32x32

28x28

24x24

in the above figure the icon size is 24 x 24

My XML files are follows

The list view

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/pure_white_color"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_icon" >
    </ExpandableListView>
```

group_icon XML in drawable is follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item   
    android:drawable="@drawable/icon_collapse" android:state_expanded="true"/>

    <item   
    android:drawable="@drawable/icon_expand"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Add this and try android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: I have solved this by set padding 0dp

Answer (score 0):

Try this you need to maintain your images in different folders in

```
res/drawable-mdpi/your_image.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/your_image.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/your_image.png       // bitmap for extra high density

small   Resources for small size screens.
normal  Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
large   Resources for large size screens.
xlarge  Resources for extra large size screens.
```

follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more deatils

Answer (score 0):

You have to use nine-patch images , normal images will stretch.. in expandable-listviewindicaor